# JMeter: Delay time between each thread create

Tags: java, multithreading, jmeter

Simple question I guess.

I have JMeter test, which has Thread Group with Number of threads = 3. Each Thred execute only one request (search on google site). Now, how to set delay between each thread creation? Lets say, 5 sec time?

> Goal:  Thread one executed | 5 seconds delay | Thread two executed | 5
>   seconds delay | Thread three executed.

Comment: Can't this be solved with the ramp up time ?

Comment: I've tried this. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a constant timer, see the docs here:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer